# How to insert a newline(\n) inside a String(text) into Cassandra by CQLSH command?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-cli

**Update**:
Newline is working if I insert the same line by python driver script.

session.execute("INSERT INTO  ctable"  + " (cid, cstring) VALUES (%s, %s)", **('2', 'row1\nrow2')**)

Still don't understand why the CQLSH command doesn't work.

**Original Question:**
I am trying to insert a very long string into Cassandra by CQLSH command, and add a '\n' to split the string into two lines when display.

I tried

```
insert into ctable (cid, cstring ) values('2', 'row1\nrow2');
insert into ctable (cid, cstring ) values('2', 'row1\\nrow2');
insert into ctable (cid, cstring ) values('2', 'row1\r\nrow2');
```

None of above statements worked, all **\n** had been treated as a regular chracter.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: cqlsh does not handle escape characters in strings in any way. If you want to insert non-printable characters like newline \n, use cassandra drivers for your language. For a long answer, see [discussion for issue CASSANDRA-8790](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8790)

Comment: Thanks! I was using python driver for Cassandra and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do it directly in CQLSH if you actually press enter while typing the string. instead of entering the characters '\n' just press enter. CQLSH should show 3 dots indicating its adding content on the new line.

I know its too late to reply but leaving the answer here for someone like me who searches this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL, just use enter:

```
insert into ctable (cid, cstring ) values('2', 'row1
row2');
```

Comment: there is a same answer from FocusBlast - why duplicate?